# Foreach results in nested divs

Tags: php, html, wordpress

The template I am working on should give me a list of items inside a parent tag. But instead of stacking them, the foreach function nests each item inside the previous. This never occured to me with a foreach function, so I am kind of puzzled here.

In the end, it should look like this:

```
<div class="artists">
  <div class="artist">
    <p>Justus Jonas</p>
  </div>
  <div class="artist">
    <p>Peter Shaw</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
$term_array = array();
?>
<div class="artists">
  <?php if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $artistName = $term->name;
  ?>
    <div class="artist">
      <p><?php echo $artistName;?></p>
    <div>
  <?php } } ?>
</div>
```

And here is the output

```
<div class="artists">
  <div class="artist">
    <p>Justus Jonas</p>
    <div>
      <div class="artist">
        <p>Peter Shaw</p>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are not closing the `<div class="artist">` - You are just missing a `/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="artist">
  <p><?php echo $artistName;?></p>
<div>
```

You open another div instead of closing it, so it has to be `</div>`

Always double check your code for syntax errors

Comment: Happens to the best of us :) Have fun coding, mate